# Applying the dual/duality principle to Boolean expressions

Tags: boolean-operations

First off, my textbook says the ***Dual Principle*** is switching ORs with ANDs and ANDs with ORs, but leaving the variables themselves in their complemented or uncomplemented form. This differs from what I've read online about the ***Duality Principle***, which states that you must interchange the ORs and ANDs *as well as* complement each individual variable. Regardless, these are just two different definitions. My question lies in how to apply the Dual and/or Duality Principle to the following situation:

```
(xy)'
```

Would the dual (according to the Duality Principle) be

```
(x' + y')'?
```

In other words, does the outside NOT stay there? Or, are all NOTs themselves, even if they are "outer NOTs" complemented? This would lead to:

```
(x' + y').
```

I'm pretty sure it is the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is like this:

```
 (x' + y')' = (x')'(y')' = xy
```

The rules applied here are:

```
 (x + y)' = x'y', and
 (x')' = x
```

Comment: Thank you. So the outer NOT does go away (when you use the more layman method of changing ANDs to ORs and ORs to ANDs as well as inverting NOTs).

Comment: Exactly, have fun with it!

Comment: However, say you wanted to go from xy to (x' + y')'. You would first change it to x + y, then x' + y', and then add an outer NOT to make it (x' + y')'? I didn't know the duality principle would require an outer NOT to always be added. Is this true?

Comment: You would do three things altogether: flip all the not, flip all the or's and and's, and have an outer not. They really happen simultaneously.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. It's just that for me to process it, it has to happen step-by-step. But I understand if they happen all at once in circuitry.